# Setup for HSQLDB in linux server

Tags: hsqldb

I am trying to setup the alias of HSQLDB for my jsp with the following command

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server -database.0 db/db1 -dbname.0 db1
```

After that i got the output as

```
dbserver:
 [java] [Server@16c9ba38]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
 [java] [Server@16c9ba38]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
 [java] [Server@16c9ba38]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
 [java] [Server@16c9ba38]: Loaded properties from [/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/Bookstore/server.properties]
 [java] [Server@16c9ba38]: Initiating startup sequence...
 [java] [Server@16c9ba38]: Server socket opened successfully in 5 ms.
 [java] [Server@16c9ba38]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:db/bookdb, alias=bookdb] opened sucessfully in 268 ms.
 [java] [Server@16c9ba38]: Startup sequence completed in 275 ms.
 [java] [Server@16c9ba38]: 2013-03-02 07:00:07.884 HSQLDB server 1.8.0 is online
 [java] [Server@16c9ba38]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
 [java] [Server@16c9ba38]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
```

I can execute the sql scripts in another other ssh connection at this stage but if i press Ctrl+C, it looks like the listener will be closed and I cannot execute other sql script.

Did i do anything wrong here? or am i suppose to do after i see the output above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the -dbname.0 is defined as db1 on your command line but is reported as bookdb in the Server output. Check you do not have a server.properties file with conflicting values.

Otherwise, there is nothing wrong. You start the serrver and it reports that it has started and ready for connection. Naturally if you press Ctrl+C, the process will be terminated.

Alternatively you can execute a shell script to run the server. This is covered fully in the Guide and there is a working script in the HSQLDB distribution package.